# Why doesn't "Custom number format" show up in Google Sheets (Google Spreadsheets)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

According to [this Google help article](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/56470?hl=en), I should be able to do the following to apply custom number formatting in a [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/intl/en_US/drive/start/apps.html#product=sheets) document.

1. Highlight the data you want to format.
2. Click the Format menu and hover over “Number” (or click the `123` number format icon in the toolbar).
3. Select *Custom number format…*.
4. Search in the menu text box to select a format. You can also add your own custom number format into the text box.
5. Click Apply.

Seems simple enough, but I don't have a *Custom number format* when I click on the `123` number format icon, or go to *Format->Number*.

I do have *Custom Decimals*, but that only allows you to specify the number of decimals.  In my case, I want a custom format that involves the percent symbol, e.g., `0.001234` is rendered as `0.1234%`.

I also have *More formats* and *More currencies*, but neither of those have *Custom number format*, nor anything that looks like what I want.

[image: number formatting options]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option is only available in the "**new Google Sheets**".

> In the new Google Sheets, you can apply custom formatting for currencies, dates, and numbers.

cf https://support.google.com/drive/answer/56470?hl=en

To activate the new Google Sheets, you can follow those instructions: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068

Comment: I didn't pick up on the fact that the "new Google Sheets" really *is* new.  I guess I read that and figured it was old language.

Comment: Also, I see that there is currently no way to "convert" existing spreadsheets (aside from manually copy/pasting each sheet).  Looking forward to that feature!

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't seem possible for now.

"All previously created spreadsheets will remain in the old version of Google Sheets **for now**."
cf https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3544847

Answer (score -1):

click in a cell > Go to Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format > type in exactly: (###) ###-#### then when you type a phone number in that cell like 1234567890 it should automatically format to (123) 456-7890.  Hope this helps.